# WordPress: Installing new plugin does not including Javascript file automatically

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have used contact form 7 multistep plugin into my Wordpress. I found that none of JS files is included automatically! 
Can anyone please help me, how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the console panel for any JS error? You may try disabling other plugins and switch the theme to default.

Looks like wp_enqueue_script not working on your case.

Comment: Hey Girish, thank you for reply. There is no JS error. I verified it. If wp_enqueue_script was not working perhaps, what should I do ?

Comment: Please do the following.
1) Disable other plugins
2) switch to default theme
3) enable logs by adding define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); in wp-config.php file

This should help you to troubleshoot the problem